# Auto generated excel file has different font every other row

Tags: .net, excel, fonts, reporting

I've been asked to fix a bug in a report that is auto-generated into an Excel file.  The bug is that every other row of the report is a different font.  The report is generated from a template.  In that template, all the rows are font A.  No sign of font B anywhere.  In the .NET code that populates the template with data, there is nothing at all about styles or fonts.  At all.  But when the report is generated, the first row is font A, the second row is font B, etc etc for all 300+ rows.

To make things even more strange, this only happens in production.  Can't replicate in dev.  I've checked the templates in prod, and even over-written it with the template from dev.  Same result.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this?

Comment: Yeah, you are right that it's not much to go on.  Wish I had more.  But... good question about the table.  I'll look into that.

Comment: Check conditional formatting as well. Someone might have wanted to color 'band' alternate rows and fouled it up. Conditional formatting changes are pretty well 'hidden' from normal investigative methods (e.g. checking style or font).